# Function within a function to alter a variable

Tags: python, function, variables

This is a simplified section of code from a game I'm *trying* to make. There is a condition in **primary_function** that if satisfied will run the **action**, in this case **secondary_function** fed into it, action itself being a function which alters a particular variable. Problem is that it doesn't alter the variable. Print(variable) returns 1.

```
variable = 1

def secondary_function(var):
    var += 1

def function(parameter_1, parameter_2, action = None, var = None):
    if condition == 'satisfied':
        action(var)

function(1, 2, secondary_function, variable)

print(variable)
```

Comment: You aren't changing the value of variable.

Comment: @Matthews Mathai I see, what alteration do you suggest? I need the code to be able to be general enough for lots of different variables and lots of different secondary_functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in Python are not passed by reference, and there is no way to do so. So a function that takes an integer argument and just increments it can never impact the original variable. If you want to modify the original variable, you will have to assign it a new value instead.

```
def secondary_function(var):
    return var + 1

variable = 1
variable = secondary_function(variable) # variable is now 2
```

Similary, you will have to modify your function `function` too to return the value instead:

```
def function (parameter_1, parameter_2, action = None, var = None):
    if parameter_1 == 1:
        return action(var)

variable = function(1, 2, secondary_function, variable)
```

Python has no notion of pass-by-reference or pass-by-value. Instead, every variable is passed *by assignment*. That means that whenever you call a function and pass a variable, the behavior is the same as if you just did `function_argument = variable`; you are assigning the *value* of the source variable to the function argument. Since Python is object oriented, this effectively means that you copy the reference to the object that `variable` refers to. As such, when the object is *mutable*, you can modify it and impact other variables referencing the same object. But for immutable objects (ints, strings, tuples, etc.), you cannot modify the existing object, so when you “modify” it, you always assign a new object to the variable, without affecting all the other variables that still point to the old object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, it's going to be hard to fit this into the rest of my code but I see it is the right way about it.

Answer (score 0):

Function arguments in Python as passed by value. Thus, `function(var)` sees a copy of `variable` in `var` and `secondary_function(var)` sees yet another copy.